# How to identify unique Android devices after Android 10+ update without IMEI, serial number, or Android Device ID?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, android-developer-api

I am developing an Android app that provides rewards to new users. However, after the Android 10+ update, IMEI, serial number are no longer reliable options for device identification due to privacy concerns. Additionally, the Google Advertising ID and Android Device ID changes after a phone reset, making it an unreliable option as well.

What are some other ways to identify unique Android devices that are reliable and won't change after a reset, even after the Android 10+ update? Are there any new options available for developers to identify unique devices in this situation?

Comment: This [question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) discusses the many approaches. (in particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59093659/3068190) gives a nice summary of them)

Comment: all the answers in that question is not for latest versions and most of them are decrypted in current version.